# Something is blocking me from overwriting css

Tags: html, css, wordpress

On the page http://project.dreamo.ee/lennumaa/wordpress/ :

The bottom-left tawk.to chat bar's width is auto; for some reason. I want it to be 320px.

I have tried !important in every css file(#tawkchat-minified-container{width: 320px !important}), custom css plugins, made sure the plugin appearance on tawk.to site has width of 320px, but still it has width:auto for some reason.

When I edit the width on google debugger, it works, but I need it to stay like that...

The funny part is, that sometimes it is 320px, and sometimes it goes full width. Not even changing anything in the meantime.

It just seems really weird to me and I cant figure out whats the problem behind this.

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: You need to include enough code in the question to create a full example of what you're talking about. Otherwise, we can't help you.

Comment: I do not see where you defined `width: 320px`? Do you have any cache plugins?

Comment: I provided the webpage that I am working on. The div name is tawkchat-minified-container.

Comment: are you injecting the css dynamically. Because the css rule is within the `style` tag in the `head`

Comment: @ClydeLobo the css probably comes with the tawk.to API.

Comment: @raulicious you can customize it. https://www.tawk.to/knowledgebase/chat-widget/customize-the-chat-widget/

Comment: yes, I have width 320px there

Comment: I posted an answer based on the fact that if I right click and Inspect the element in Google tools, change the width to `320px !important` it works

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apply the `width` to the parent `iframe` if you cannot edit the iframe's **CSS** itself.

```
#tawkchat-minified-iframe-element {
   width: 320px !important;
}
```

OR Edit the **HTML** directly since the CSS is written inline:

```
<iframe id="tawkchat-minified-iframe-element" src="about:blank" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" class="" style="width: 320px;max-width: 100%;outline: none !important;visibility: visible !important;resize: none !important;box-shadow: none !important;overflow: visible !important;opacity: 1 !important;position: fixed !important;border: 0px !important;padding: 0px !important;transition-property: none !important;z-index: 1000001 !important;cursor: auto !important;float: none !important;height: 40px !important;min-height: 40px !important;max-height: 40px !important;min-width: 320px !important;transform: rotate(0deg) translateZ(0px) !important;transform-origin: 0px center 0px !important;margin: 0px !important;top: auto !important;bottom: 0px !important;left: 10px !important;right: auto !important;display: block !important;background: none transparent !important;"></iframe>
```

`#tawkchat-minified-container` is not relevant because it is inside an `iframe`, which does not inherit the general `CSS`/`JS` codes of your WordPress theme.

P.S There is a lot of unnecessary code here, try cleaning it up.

Comment: Thank you for answering, but the css still does'nt work and I cant find the html file, since the plugin itself only has 2 .php files, which dont have iframe inside them.

Answer (score 0):

Add this script

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $( document ).ready(function() {
    jQuery("#tawkchat-minified-iframe-element").css("width","320px");
  });
</script>
```

VIA CSS :

```
#tawkchat-minified-iframe-element, #tawkchat-minified-iframe-element html, #tawkchat-minified-iframe-element body {
    width: 320px !important;
}
```

Comment: @Aziz : I wanted to provide both solution to raulicious.

Comment: @raulicious Try css fix first

Comment: After applying that css, it still shows width:auto on browser.

Comment: @raulicious : Try adding the css code of jquery code just before the `</body>` tag